# Show user fullname via joined databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

and I'm stuck.

I'm currently trying to print out the column **fullname**, in the database **User**.

I have the databases connected like this.

4 models. Company, Application, Answer, User.

The Company created an application, that can be answered by the user.

The **company.rb**

```
has_many :applications
has_many :answers, through: :applications
```

The **application.rb**

```
belongs_to :company
has_many :answers
```

The **answer.rb**

```
belongs_to :application
has_many :users
```

The **user.rb**

```
has_many :answers
```

The company creates a set of questions, those are stored in application. The user can view those question and answer them. The answers are stored in answer. When they answer I store their user_id in answer.rb.

What I am trying to do is show the company which user answered their question. I've been able to print out their user_id, but not their .fullname.

This is how my current setup looks:

```
<h1>People who've applied to your startup</h1>

<% @applications.all.each do |application| %>
 <% application.answers.each do |answer| %>

  <p>Your question1: <%= answer.application.question_1 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 1: <%= answer.answer_1 %></p>
 <p>Your question 2: <%= answer.application.question_2 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 3: <%= answer.answer_2 %></p>
  <p>Your question 3: <%= answer.application.question_3 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 3: <%= answer.answer_3 %></p>


  <i>Answered by user: <%= answer.user_id %></i>
  <hr>
```

This successfully prints out their user_id. However I want to go one step deeper and get access to their fullname. So how do I do that? Their fullname is stored in the user.rb model.

Comment: Try giving it like this `<%= answer.user.fullname %>`

Comment: @Pavan I got, undefined method `user'

Comment: Your associations seems to be wrong.You should be having `belongs_to :user` in `answer.rb` not `has_many :users`.Change it and try again.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,your **`Relation`** between **`User`** and **`Answer`** seems to be wrong.You should be having **`belongs_to :user`** in **`Answer`** model not **`has_many :users`**.

```
#answer.rb
Class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :application
belongs_to :user #here

end
```

Secondly,by doing so,you can do like this

```
<%= answer.user.fullname %>
```

to get the associated **`user's fullname`** for an **`answer`**.

And also you should look into these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)** for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I thing a better answer would be:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :user #here
  delegate :fullname, to: 'user', allow_nil: true, (optional) prefix: 'user'
end
```

Now you can do

```
<%=answer.fullname%> or if you add the optional part <%=answer.user_fullname%>
```

Read more if you prefare this way
[delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

The prefix does not have to be called 'user'

```
delegate :fullname, to: 'user', allow_nil: true, prefix: 'any_name'

<%= answer.any_name_fullname%>
```

Comment: I like delegate better, too.  If you're going to prefix with the property to which you're delegating, you can just say `prefix: true`.  `delegate :fullname, to: :user, allow_nil: true, prefix: true` will yield the same result as above.